# How can i save the data of the page while routing thought my website pages? (Vue vue-router)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

i can't get how to don't lose data when i route from a page to another, for example i realized a todo list in which i can add,edit,remove tasks. But if i add a task and then switch to another page when i return to my todo page the added task is gone.

How can i make possible to store data of a page when i route to another page?

I am using Vue and vue-router

Here is my todo page:

```
 <template>
 <div id="todolist" class="container">
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<input
  type="text"
  class="todo-input-text form-control w-50 mt-4 mb-4"
  placeholder="Insert task"
  v-model="newtask"
  @keyup.enter="addTodo"
/>
<div class="todo-item w-50 row" v-for="(todo, index) in tasksFilter" :key="todo.id">
  <input
    class="form-check-input bg-blue position-static"
    type="checkbox"
    v-model="todo.completed"
  />
  <div
    v-if="!todo.editing"
    @dblclick="editTodo(todo)"
    :class="{completed : todo.completed}"
    class="col-10"
  >{{todo.task}}</div>
  <input
    v-else
    type="text"
    @keyup.enter="doneEdit(todo)"
    class="todo-input-edit col10 form-control"
    v-model="todo.task"
  />
  <span @passinguserID="passinguserID">{{userID}}</span>
  <div v-if="todo.editing" class="removeitem col-2 text-right" @click="returnTodo(todo)">Return</div>
  <div class="removeitem col-2 text-right" @click="removeTodo(index)">Remove</div>
</div>

<div class="todo-item mt-4 w-50 row footerlist">
  <div>
    <input
      id="checkallbox"
      type="checkbox"
      @change="checkallmanually"
      :checked="checkallauto"
      class="form-check-input position-static"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="col-9" style="left:-7px;">
    <label>Check all</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3" style="white-space:no-wrap">
    <span>
      Pending :
      <b
        :class="{notaskleft : remainingitem==0}"
        style="transition:0.25s;"
      >{{remainingitem}}</b>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="final-container">
  <div class="w-50 row mt-4" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <button
      class="btn btn-dark col-2"
      :class="{ active: filter =='all'}"
      @click="filter = 'all'"
    >All</button>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <button
      class="btn btn-dark col-2"
      :class="{ active: filter =='active'}"
      @click="filter = 'active'"
    >Pending</button>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <button
      class="btn btn-dark col-2"
      :class="{ active: filter =='completed'}"
      @click="filter = 'completed'"
    >Done</button>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin:0 auto;" class="row w-50 mt-5">
    <button
      style="margin:0 auto;"
      class="btn btn-danger col-4 mb-5"
      v-if="showclearbutton"
      @click="clearcompleted"
    >Clear completed</button>
  </div>
</div>
<login></login>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import login from "./login.vue";

export default {
name: "Todolist",
components: {
login
},
data() {
return {
  newtask: "",
  idfor: 3,
  filter: "all",
  archive: [],
  tasks: [
    {
      id: 1,
      task: "Finish the todo list",
      completed: false,
      editing: false,
      savelbl: "",
      userID: this.userID
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      task: "cane",
      completed: false,
      editing: false,
      savelbl: "",
      userID: this.userID
      }
    ]
  };
 },
 computed: {
 remainingitem: function() {
  return this.tasks.filter(todo => !todo.completed).length;
 },
 checkallauto: function() {
  return this.remainingitem == 0;
 },
  tasksFilter: function() {
  if (this.filter == "all") {
    return this.tasks;
  } else if (this.filter == "active") {
    return this.tasks.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
  } else if (this.filter == "completed") {
    if (this.tasks.filter(todo => todo.completed).length > 0)
      return this.tasks.filter(todo => todo.completed);
    else {
      alert("no task completed");
      this.defaultFilter();
    }
  }
  return this.tasks;
  },
   showclearbutton: function() {
    return this.tasks.filter(todo => todo.completed).length > 0;
   }
   },
   directives: {
   focus: {
   // directive definition
     inserted: function(el) {
     el.focus();
    } 
   }
  },
   methods: {
   addTodo: function() {
   if (this.newtask != "") {
    this.tasks.push({
      id: this.idFor,
      task: this.newtask,
      completed: false,
      editing: false,
      savelbl: "",
      userID: this.userID
    });

    this.newtask = "";
    this.idfor++;
    } else alert("task cannot be empty");
    },
     removeTodo: function(index) {
      this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
     },
      editTodo: function(todo) {
       todo.savelbl = todo.task;
       todo.editing = true;
      },
     doneEdit: function(todo) {
      if (todo.task != "") todo.editing = false;
      else alert("task cannot be empty");
      },
      returnTodo: function(todo) {
      todo.task = todo.savelbl;
      todo.editing = false;
      },
      checkallmanually: function() {
      this.tasks.forEach(todo => (todo.completed = event.target.checked));
      },
      clearcompleted: function() {
      this.archive.push(this.tasks.filter(todo => todo.completed));
      this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
      this.filter = "all";
      },
      defaultFilter: function() {
      this.filter = "all";
      },
      passinguserID: function(data) {
      this.tasks.userID = data;
      }
     }
    };
 </script>

 <style lang="scss">
 @import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css");
 .todo-input-text {
 margin: 0 auto;
 }

  .todo-input-edit {
  max-width: 360px !important;
  line-height: 1.5 !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  }

 .todo-item {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  }
  .removeitem {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: end;
  &:hover {
  color: rgb(29, 102, 212);
  transition: 0.25s;
 }
}

.edititem {
cursor: pointer;
&:hover {
color: rgb(29, 102, 212);
transition: 0.25s;
}
}

.completed {
 text-decoration: line-through;
 opacity: 0.7;
 font-style: italic;
}

.footerlist {
 border-top: 1px solid lightslategray;
 line-height: 24.5px;
 font-size: 14px;
 }
.notaskleft {
 color: green;
font-size: 16px;
 transition: 0.25s;
 }
 </style>
```

And my app page where i set the router

```
 <template>
 <div id="app" class="container">
   <div id="nav" style="margin:0 auto;" class="logo mb-5 mt-2 p-0">
      <img class="logo" alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
      <a><router-link to="/completed">Completed</router-link></a>
      <a><router-link to="/todolist">todolist</router-link></a>


  </div>
   <!-- <Todolist></Todolist> -->
   <!-- <completed></completed>     -->
  <router-view/>

  </div>
</template>
<script>

</script>
<style>
 *{
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .logo{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
   max-height: 100px;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  #app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   /* text-align: center; */
   color: #2c3e50;
   }

    #nav {
    padding: 30px;
    display: block;
   }

   #nav a {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #2c3e50;
  }

  #nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
  }
  </style>
```

And there the page where i route to and then lose the data on the todo page

```
<template>
<div>
    completed tasks here
</div>
</template>
<script>

export default{}

</script>
```

So the point is how to don't lose data on switching pages, if i add a task on my todo page how can i mantain it also when i get back to it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. The recommended way to keep state across components is to use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), which gives you a single place to store you data that can then be shared across your components, or just saved until you come back to the same component again.
2. Save the data in localeStorage or a cookie as changes are made, or when you leave the component. You can then load it back again later, when you need it.
3. Use [<keep-alive>](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components), which will cache your components in memory meaning the state wont be lost when you change from and to it. However, this will use more memory on the clients machine so beaware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for that. It manages your app's state. However it is not persistent by default. You can write a vuex action that stores your changes in the localStorage to make it persistent even after a site reload.

Comment: I tought to use Vuex but i was asked to do with vue-router and i am totally stuck

Comment: You should not persist data with vue-router. For this specific purpose it's better to use vuex. Vue Router can be used if you need to store the state of the website, and want to let other's be able to see that too. You then would pass the data in queries.